# How to rename a file inside a folder using a shell command?

Tags: unix, shell, zsh

I have a file at `some/long/path/to/file/myfiel.txt`.

I want to rename it to `some/long/path/to/file/myfile.txt`.

Currently I do it by `mv some/long/path/to/file/myfiel.txt some/long/path/to/file/myfile.txt`, but typing the path twice isn't terribly effective (even with tab completion).

How can I do this faster? (I think I can write a function to change the filename segment only, but that's plan B).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To do this in a single command, you can simply do this:

```
mv some/long/path/to/file/{myfiel.txt,myfile.txt}
```

Which is an example for the full file name, given that it's a typo you can do something like:

```
mv some/long/path/to/file/myfi{el,le}.txt
```

Both will expand to the full command, these are called [brace expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace). They are [supported by zsh](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/workshops/zsh/brace.html).

Comment: Oh my, this opens so much possibilities. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here are several options:

Change to the directory:

```
cd /home/long/path
mv file1 file2
cd -
```

Change directories using the directory stack:

```
pushd /some/long/path
mv file1 file2
popd
```

Change to the directory using a subshell:

```
( 
  cd /some/long/path
  mv file1 file2
)   # no need to change back
```

Use brace expansion:

```
mv /some/long/path/{file1,file2}
```

Use a variable:

```
D=/some/long/path
mv "$D/file1" "$D/file2"
```

Comment: Beware that the last approach breaks when the path has a space, beter quote it.

Comment: @slhck **ALL** of the approaches break if you have spaces.

Comment: No, if you type them correctly they won't. Only the variable when expanded will look like multiple arguments to mv

Comment: @slhck there you go.

Answer (score 3):

Change to the directory, move the file, and change back to the previous directory; like so:

```
cd some/long/path/to/file
mv myfiel.txt myfile.txt
cd -
```

Answer (score 1):

When I use the subshell method I would tend to do it on one line like so

```
(cd /some/long/path ; mv myfiel myfile )
```